# why python all([[False, True],[False, False]]) is considered True

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean

The title is almost saying all. If I ask Python what is `all(test = [[False, True],[False, False]])` it outputs True:

```
all(test)
Out[279]: True
```

I was playing with Python's boolean values and found this one hard to understand.

If I make it into a Numpy array, `test = np.array([[False, True],[False, False]])`, it outputs False:

```
test.all()
Out[283]: False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool question. Best way to approach this, is to try it out for oneself in a Python REPL:

```
$ python
[Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> bool([False])
True
>>> bool(False)
False
>>> all([[]])
False
>>> all([[False]])
True
```

But hey, who am I but a humble raven, standing atop the shoulders of giants here. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75935171/10237506) here for more details and clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy does it in a more math-focused way where it actually looks at all the values in all the lists. The Python interpreter, on the other hand, looks at it from a programmatic way.

The reason `all([[False, True],[False, False]])` evaluates to `True` is due to two quirks of Python.

1. The `all(iterable)` function looks at each element in the iterable and checks if they are all truthy.
2. A list that is not empty is truthy`.

The `all()` function checks each element in the super list and sees that it is structured `[list, list]`. But instead of going into each sublist, `all()` simply evaluates whether each sublist is "truthy". Since the sublists all have values within them, they're both truthy and thus evaluates to `True`. In the end, `all()` only sees that the super list is made of two truthy elements, and thus it returns `True`.

Answer (score 0):

In python, non-empty lists are "truthy"

```
>>> bool([False, True])
True
```

`all` doesn't look any deeper into an object than that. You gave it two non-empty lists, you got `True` in return.

`ndarray.all` does the same thing, except it looks deeper into the array. That's the point of numpy - it broadcasts an operation to its elements. You can tweak how that's done with its parameters such as `axis` which would consider subsets of the array.

You could do something similar with vanilla python by iterating the inner lists:

```
>>> test = [[False, True],[False, False]]
>>> all(val for inner in t2 for val in inner)
False
```